# Add aditional field with title to every node

Tags: nodes

I am trying to add additional field to nodes. I could add the field but I can't find a way to add its title. I have implemented the hook_node_view . 
My code is

```
function cso_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  $node->content['my_additional_field'] = array(
      '#markup' => "additional field",
      '#title' => "additional title",
      '#weight' => 1000
    );
}
```

The title is not appearing where the node is being printed. How can I add the title for this additional field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there's no generic `#title` property (it's certainly not mentioned in the [render array docs](https://drupal.org/node/930760)); forms use them, but I don't think extends to any render array.

`#prefix` would be the way to go:

```
$content['my_additional_field'] = array(
  '#markup' => "additional field",
  '#prefix' => "<h3>Title</h3>",
  '#weight' => 1000
);
```